# Firebase hosting bloquea los End point

Tags: nodejs, angular, firebase

estoy usando el hosting de firebase para una aplicación bew echa en angular, mi web envía y recibe datos de una api que esta en otro servidor.

Lo que pasa es que firebase me bloquea todas las solicitudes http que realiza mi web,  las salientes es decir no deja que mi web haga ninguna solicitud y aparece bloqueada, como podria arreglar esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! 
Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganar tu primera medalla. 
También te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. 
Con los datos que proporcionas es muy difícil que recibas ayuda.

Comment: Debes pagar por Firebase, la versión gratuita no permite realizar peticiones fuera del server.

Comment: en realidad si se pueden hacer endpoints externos, solo que deben ser a servidores seguros es decir conexiones https